# How can i add multiple rows in DICOM dataset?

Tags: c#, fo-dicom

How can i add multiple rows in DICOM dataset? Without using another DICOM
dataset like `List<DicomDataset>`?

```
dt = dac.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand).Tables[0];
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
  {
    DicomDataset _dataset = new DicomDataset();
    _dataset.Add(DicomTag.SOPClassUID, SOPClassUID);
    _dataset.Add(DicomTag.SOPInstanceUID, GenerateUid());

    _dataset.Add(DicomTag.PatientID, dr["PatientID"].ToString());
    _dataset.Add(DicomTag.PatientName, dr["PatientName"].ToString());
    _dataset.Add(DicomTag.PatientBirthDate, dr["DOB"].ToString());
    _dataset.Add(DicomTag.PatientSex, dr["Sex"].ToString());

    _dataset.Add(DicomTag.AccessionNumber, dr["AccessionNumber"].ToString());
    _dataset.Add(DicomTag.RequestedProcedureDescription, dr["Procedure_Description"].
        ToString());
    _dataset.Add(DicomTag.RequestedProcedureID, dr["RequestedProcedureId"].ToString());
    _dataset.Add(DicomTag.Modality, dr["modality"].ToString());                           
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do. Are you trying to transfer data from the `DataRow`s to a number of `DicomDataset`s? Or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the internal structure of `DicomDataset` we can see that when you add multiple items, the following methods are called

```
public DicomDataset Add<T>(DicomTag tag, params T[] values)
{
    return DoAdd(tag, values, false);
}

private DicomDataset DoAdd<T>(DicomTag tag, IList<T> values, bool allowUpdate)
{
    [...]
    return DoAdd(vr, tag, values, allowUpdate);
}
```

which eventually results in a call like this

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) 
    return DoAdd(new DicomApplicationEntity(tag, values.Cast<string>().ToArray()), allowUpdate);
```

Which adds `DicomApplicationEntity` objects with the arrays you are passing. Anyway, when you are trying to add multiple objects with the same tag it will fail, since the internal dictionary can only hold one object per type. Hence I guess, that you can add multiple rows for one tag with

```
_dataset.Add(DicomTag.PatientID, dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(row => row["PatientID"].ToString()).ToArray());
```